# $\lim \limits_{h\to \infty} \left(\frac{f(10+\frac{1}{h})}{f(10)}\right)^h $ given that $ f(10) = 5, f'(10)=2$

Tags: calculus, limits

Trying to find this limit: 
$\lim \limits_{h\to \infty} \left(\frac{f(10+\frac{1}{h})}{f(10)}\right)^h $
given that $ f(10) = 5, f'(10)=2$.

Tried: take the log of the limit, then it becomes 
$\lim \limits_{h\to \infty} h\left(\log\left(f(10+\frac{1}{h})\right)-\log f(10)\right) $

I couldn't find a way to make use of  $f'(10)=2$...

Any hint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take log, $$\lim \limits_{h\to \infty} h\left(\log \left(f\left(10+\frac{1}{h}\right)\right)-\log f(10)\right)=\lim \limits_{h\to \infty} \frac{\left(\log \left(f\left(10+\frac{1}{h}\right)\right)-\log f(10)\right)}{\frac{1}{h}}$$
Since $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=10$, and by assumption, $\log f(x)$ differentiable at $x=10$.

Then original limit is $(\log f(x))'$ at $x=10$. Then use continuity of exponential function, we get the result, which is $e^{\frac{2}{5}}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: let $h = 1/n$ so that $n \rightarrow 0^+$ as $h \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

By Taylor,
$f(10+\frac{1}{h})
=f(10)+\frac{f'(10)}{h}+O(\frac1{h^2})
$
so
$\left(\frac{f(10+\frac{1}{h})}{f(10)}\right)
=\left(\frac{f(10)+\frac{f'(10)}{h}+O(\frac1{h^2})}{f(10)}\right)
=1+\frac{f'(10)}{10h}+O(\frac1{h^2})
$.

Since
$(1+a/h)^h
\to e^a
$
as $h \to \infty$,
$(1+\frac{f'(10)}{10h}+O(\frac1{h^2}))^h
\to e^{f'(10)/10)}
$.